# Orchard Truncate Blog Rss Description

Tags: rss, orchardcms

Orchard includes the entire blog post description in its RSS feeds. I need to provide an alternate feed that truncates this to either the first paragraph or by a max character count. What is the recommended way to do this in Orchard?

Comment: Orchard is a CMS build on ASP.NET MVC - http://www.orchardproject.net/

Comment: You can override views in Orchard with your own. Use the Shape Tracer to find the correct alternate and make it your own.

Comment: I don't think alternates apply here. RSS feeds don't get produced by views.